# Override method name in resource route

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-5

```
    Route::resource('/api/ranking/firmware', 'Ranking\FirmwareController',
                    ['only' => ['index'], 'names' => ['index' => 'api.ranking.firmware.firmware']]);
```

It works when I set name 'index', but I want to access same method with 'firmware' name inside FirmwareController.

Answer (score 1):

[Resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) has only rest interfaces, which included index, create, store, show, edit, update, delete. It's because of ideology of [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) services. However, you can make a regular controller.

```
Route::controller('/api/ranking/firmware', 'Ranking\FirmwareController', [
    'firmware' => 'api.ranking.firmware.firmware',
]);
```

Comment: I know, I need RESTful GET method, but don't want to call it index, there is a way to override http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers with 'names'. But it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: try to change names like this ranking.firmware.firmware

Comment: Doesn't work, and firmware.firmware same. @vanadium23

Comment: Laravel very strict in namespaces, try to make your class Ranking\FirmwareController as Api\Ranking\FirmwareController, or group routes /api with method Router::group

Comment: I tried but it always search for 'index'. Nevermind, I could keep on with index :). Thank you anyway.